# where to put device_admin_sample.xml?

Tags: android, android-manifest

where to put the '**device_admin_sample.xml**', its giving error wherever I put it..

**device_admin_sample.xml**

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-policies>
<limit-password />
<watch-login />
<reset-password />
<force-lock />
<wipe-data />
</uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be in your /res/xml folder.

Here is a sample from ApiDemos:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/xml/device_admin_sample.html