# Which directory do it put the network_security_config.xml in Xamarin Forms app, when building to android

Tags: android

As the questions states, however, even following the documentation I can't find it.

Here is a similar question with similar question: [where to put device_admin_sample.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773632/where-to-put-device-admin-sample-xml)

I have put the `network_security_config.xml` into the following folders:

```
ROOT.ANDROID/network_security_config.xml
ROOT.ANDROID/res/network_security_config.xml
ROOT.ANDROID/res/xml/network_security_config.xml
ROOT.ANDROID/Resources/network_security_config.xml
ROOT.ANDROID/Resources/xml/network_security_config.xml
ROOT.ANDROID/Resources/res/network_security_config.xml
ROOT.ANDROID/Resources/rest/xml/network_security_config.xml
```

And none of them seem to work. here is the manifest code;

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
</application>
```

Here is the inside of the xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">google.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I've noted by default there is no `res` folder, but instead a `Resources`, so is it possible there was an update that made the location wrong? Should I by putting it under the Android Project? is it because the I have an `xml` extention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out when using Xamarin Forms you can use a specific format you can use to reference files:

```
$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/CustomPath/file.config
```

Comment: Could you provide more documentation on how to do this?  I follow MSBuildProjectDirectory.  Where do I set the CustomPath? In the Android Manifest?

Answer (score 2):

i got error "failed to processing manifest"
"resource xml/network_security_config not found" to get rid of that after
add the networksecurityconfig.xml file, make sure the build action is set to AndroidResource.
to do that right click on network_security_config then properties build action set to **AndroidResource**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpLko.png)